# How to Restrict Unauthorized Access To A Particular Domain Without IP

Tags: .htaccess, file, private

I wanted to know how can I restrict unauthorized access to my website. For example:
I have a domain example.com and a subdomain sub.example.com that contains some personal files and projects (like .css or .js) that are needed to be linked to example.com and its subdomains. I want to restrict unauthorized access to sub.example.com such that i can only be accessed by example.com and its other subdomains.

For others it should display unauthorized access (error 403). And also it should not be displayed if searched directly from web engine. Also the files should not be viewed or downloaded through example.com. Can someone tell me how to do it with .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on the top of your sub.example.com .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http://|https://)([^.]+\.)?(example.com).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,R=403,L]
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the above code so I can edit according to my needs! @JarekBaran

Comment: I actually want to access style.css file from sub.example.com server for multiple subdomains of example.com and don't want to code tobe accessible to others. @JarekBaran

Comment: If referrer is not example.com, sub.example.com, any.example.com or not referrer is send Apache return HTTP 403 for any request.

Comment: I managed to enable access for sub.example.comby other subdomains. But, now the problem is that i want to access a .css file via other .html file. I don't want to allow anyone to redirect to sub.example.com from example.com. I just want to access the .css file without letting the browser view or download it by someone! @JarekBaran

Comment: Actually i wanted to password protect the subdomain but when I do so, The browser asks for password when I link .css file to html